# Django update a row

Tags: django

Hi I am trying to update a row in django but I am getting the error

```
update_form() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here is my code:

view.py:

```
def update_form(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a=newleave.objects.get(id=id)
        form = leave_application(request.POST, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('successful.html')
    else:
        a=newleave.objects.get(id=id)
        form = leave_application(instance=a)
    return render_to_response('update_form.html'{'form':form},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form.py:

```
class leave_application(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = newleave
        fields =('First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'department', 'position', 'leave_type',             'Specify_details', 'start_Date', 'end_date', 'total_working_days', 'username')
```

update_form.html:

```
<form action ="/update_form/" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
<table>
{{form.as_table}}
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Record" >
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your urls.py.

The `update_form` view takes an argument `id`, so you should include it in the url pattern.

```
url(r'^update_form/(?P<id>\d+)/$', update_form, name='update_form')
```

For example, to edit the object with id=1, you would go to `/update_form/1/`

You would have to include the id in the template context

```
return render_to_response('update_form.html'{'form':form, 'id': id},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And include it it the form action:

```
<form action ="/update_form/{{ id }}/" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
```

Using the url tag would be slightly better:

```
<form action ="{% url 'update_form' %}" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `id` of the row to the `update_form` view:

```
<form action="{% url 'update_form' id %}" method="post">
```

And in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^update_form/(?P<id>\d+)/$', update_form, name='update_form'),
```